# How can I store data keyed in by user from multiple field boxes into a string of data?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database, string

### HTML:

```
   <div id="room_fileds">
        <div class='label'>Tickets:</div>
        <div id="content">
            <span>Ticket: <input type="text" style="width:48px;" name="width[]" value="" /></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

### JS:

```
function add_fields() {
    var d = document.getElementById("content");

      d.innerHTML += "<br /><span>Ticket: <input 
type='text'style='width:48px;'value='' /></span> ";
}
```

Hi, I want to insert a string of data into the database through user's input in multiple field boxes

So for example,

When user wants to sell 2 tiers of tickets, the user press the add more button which comes out another field box, with a total of 2 field boxes. And lets say the user sell the 1st tier of ticket at $10 and 2nd tier of ticket at $5, I would want the data to be keyed in to the database as a string 10, 5 in a single variable.

So the database will appear as:

```
EventID    Ticket Price

   1           10,5
```

Comment: You will regret storing your data this way when you come to search it. I would suggest (for your example data) storing two rows, 1 of `(1, 10)` and 1 of `(1, 5)`.

Comment: What will you suggest as my main point is to store it in a single variable as well as also for me to easily retrieve the data when i need it

Comment: I need not necessarily need my data to be visually seen easily in my database, as long as i can easily retrieve each price in the single variable

Comment: If you store it in separate rows, you can still easily retrieve it into a single variable by using a grouping query (with `GROUP BY`) and functions like `GROUP_CONCAT`. Storing single values makes it easier (for example) to find all events that have a ticket price of 10.